# Set Alarm to Repeat only 3 Times

Tags: android

I am using the AlarmManager.setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation) Method in order to set a repeating Alarm. Meanwhile, I would like to set the Alarm to repeat only 3 times, and not indefinitely as this Method does. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable in SharedPreferences termed *alarmCount* which we'll *increment in AlarmReceiver* class (in onReceive() method).

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TIMER", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("alarmCount", 1);
        editor.commit();
```

We set the alarm using the following code -

```
private void setAlarm() {
    int alarmId = 0;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("alarmId", alarmId);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            alarmId, intent,
            0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 1, alarmIntent);
    Log.e("alarm", "set");
}
```

According the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#cancel) -

> Depending on your app, you may want to include the ability to cancel
>   the alarm. To cancel an alarm, call cancel() on the Alarm Manager,
>   passing in the PendingIntent you no longer want to fire.

Thus, you'll then code the AlarmReceiver to **cancel** the alarm once count reaches 3.

Then, in our AlarmReceiver, we match the alarmId we used earlier, and cancel the same alarm once count reaches 3.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int alarmId = intent.getExtras().getInt("alarmId");
        PendingIntent alarmIntent;
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmId, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class),
                0);
        //increment alarmCount
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("TIMER", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        int alarmCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("alarmCount", 1);
        editor.putInt("alarmCount", alarmCount+1);
        editor.commit();
        Log.e("alarmCount ", alarmCount+"");

        if(alarmCount == 3) {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
        Log.e("Alarm","Cancelled");
        }
```

As you can see from the [sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQMPs.png), the alarm did not repeat after being cancelled (no logs).

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer Kunal. As soon as I have a chance to try your solution, I will let you know the result. Joseph

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: Hi Kunal, Your Solution works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help. Joseph

Comment: @JF0001 glad to be of help ! :)

Comment: how we can achieve this with intent only that is using in pending intent e.g. Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class); intent.putExtras("alarmCount", 1); what should we have to do in onReceive() to increase this value?